# JqGrid and custom classes

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

Is it possible to tune jqGrid to add some classes to inputs in EditForm? For example, I can add classes to cells by specifying property `classes` in `colModel` section. And I want to know, is similar mechanism for inputs exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no exact property like `classes` in [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options), but you can use `dataInit` callback of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) to add the class or do other kind of initializing action on the input fields. For example the code

```
editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
```

add predefined 'ui-state-highlight' class of jQuery UI (see [here](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137970/jQuery%20UI%20CSS%20Framework)) to the input box. As the result you can receive the result like the following

[image]

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CSSCalssesInDialogFields.htm) where I added CSS class `'ui-state-highlight'` to the `'Client'` field and the class `'ui-state-error'` to the `'Tax'` field.